# How to find $\max|f(z)|$ in complex analysis?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

The $M-L$ estimation lemma inequality states:

$$\left |\int_\Gamma f(z) dz\right| < ML(\Gamma)$$

Where $M = \max|f(z)|$ and $L(\Gamma)$ is the arc length of $\Gamma$.

Here: [Wikipedia: Estimation Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma)

But how do we find the maximum of the modulus of $f(z)$?

Take the simpler example:

$$f(z) = \frac{\log(z)}{z^2 + 1}$$

How do we find the maximum using a semi-circle contour, with large radius $R$? Such that the parameter is:

$$z = Re^{i\theta}$$

I am confused about this "maximum" system, I can find a bound, but the lemma **requires** the maximum, which is what is the confusion here.

Thanks. Any help is welcome.

Comment: If you know that $|f(z)| \le M'$ for all $z \in \Gamma$, then $M = \max_{z \in \Gamma} |f(z)| \le M'$. So, you can use the bound instead of the actual maximum.

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia page you cited?

Comment: The lemma does *not* require this - it only requires $M$ to be an upper bound. Try reading the lemma (and the proof) again.

Comment: @Winther, thats weird. It says it has to be **overall** maximum??

Comment: Did you read the wiki page you linked to? "$\ldots$ and if its absolute value $|f (z)|$ is bounded by a constant $M$ for all $z$ on $\Gamma$, then$\ldots$" Thus the lemma does not require $M$ to be the exact maximum, it just has to be at least as big as the maximum, i.e. an upper bound. The paragraph that might be confusing you "In particular, we may take the maximum" does not say that we must take $M$ as the maximum, but that this is one choice we might take.

Comment: @Winther, I did read it several times. So I see, the criterion. The idea is to have some upperbound Such as the upperbound $U$:

$$U \le M$$ 

Where $M$ is the global maximum.

Comment: To apply the lemma you have to find a $M$ such that $|f(z)| \leq M$ for all $z$ on the curve $\Gamma$. That is all that is to it. The constant $M$ can be whatever you want as long as $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all $z$ on the curve $\Gamma$.

Comment: @Winther Thats a problem. The maximum principle says analytic functions dont have $|f(z)| \le M$ The principle says this statement is false.

Comment: "...on the curve $\Gamma$..." *Not* bounded everywhere! For example $f(z) = z$ satisfy $|f(z)| \leq 1$ on the unit circle.

Comment: @Winther, I dont understand, where did you get that from?

Comment: Read the lemma (wiki page) in detail again! It says clearly "$\ldots$and if its absolute value $|f(z)|$ is bounded by a constant $M$ for all $z$ on $\Gamma\ldots$". The constant $M$ is an upper bound on the curve $\Gamma$, not globally (which clearly does not exist)!

Comment: So like $Re^{i\theta}$ is $M$??

Comment: No, that is a parametrization of the curve. $M$ is an upper bound for $|f(z)|$ for $z$ on that curve. For example, if we let the curve $\Gamma$ be a circle with radius $R$ (which we can describe by $z = Re^{i\theta}$ by varying $\theta$) and if we take $f(z) = z^4$ then we find $|f(z)| = |R e^{i\theta}|^4 = R^4$ so $M=R^4$ is an upper bound for $|f(z)|$ on $\Gamma$.

Comment: @Winther, $R^5 > R^4$ cant that be an upperbound? This is the point, there is always a function greater than another function, so what is the "stopping point?"

Comment: Sure it is. Any upper bound would do so if you want to pick $R^5$ instead feel free to do so (however a choice like $M = R^5$ might not be good enough to prove stuff like $\left|\int_\Gamma f(z) dz\right| \leq M(R)L(R) \to 0$ as $R\to \infty$ as the lemma is most often used for).

Comment: I see, so it is a personal choice?

Comment: Yes. As long as it is correct and that it is 'tight enough' to make your subsequent argument go through (the thing you are using the lemma for) then it does not matter what you choose for $M$.

Comment: @Winther, thanks. Can I ask you something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

$$\left| \int_\Gamma f(z) \text{d} z\right| \leqslant \int_\Gamma |f(z)| |\text{d} z| \leqslant \operatorname*{max}_{z\in \Gamma}|f(z)| \int_\Gamma |\text{d} z| = \operatorname*{max}_{z\in \Gamma}|f(z)| \ell(\Gamma)$$

Where $\ell(\Gamma)$ is the length of the contour.

#### Example

In the case of $f(z) = \frac{\log z}{z^2+1}$.

On the semi-circle $z(\theta) = Re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta: 0\to \pi$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{\log z}{z^2+1}\right| &= \left|\frac{\log Re^{i\theta}}{R^2e^{2i\theta}+1}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{\log{R} +i\theta}{R^2e^{2i\theta}+1}\right| \\
&\leqslant\frac{\log{R} +\theta}{R^2-1}\\
&\leqslant\frac{\log{R} +\pi}{R^2-1}
\end{align}$$

Such that if $R$ big enough (and $\ell(\Gamma) = R\pi$)

$$\left| \int_\Gamma f(z) \text{d} z\right| \leqslant \frac{\log{R} +\pi}{R^2-1}\cdot R\pi$$

Comment: How is $|\log(R) + i\theta| \le \log(R) + \theta$ ???

Comment: Triangle inequality: $|\log R + i\theta| \leqslant |\log R|+|i\theta| = \log R + \theta$ if $R$ big enough.

Comment: Can I ask you another question?